# Replace white space in filename with hyphen

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the following line to rename an mp4 file by adding a timestamp to the end of the name.

```
    mediaName_ts = "%s_%s.mp4" %(pfile, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
```

But I have problems accessing the file when the filename has white space: 
`name file test.mp4`

How can I remove the white space, replace it with a hyphen and append the time stamp to end of the filename?

So the file name will be: `name-file-test_2016-02-11_08:11:02.mp4`

I already did the timestamp part, but not the whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

For replacing the whitespace with a hyphen, use the builtin [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method:

```
string = "name file test"
print(string)
#name file test
string = string.replace(" ", "-")
#name-file-test
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, it uses `os.path` to manipulate the filename:

```
import re
import os
import time

def timestamp_filename(filename):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    name = re.sub(r'[ ,]', '-', name)      # add any whitespace characters here
    return '{}_{}{}'.format(name, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()), ext)

print timestamp_filename("name file test.mp4")
```

This would display:

```
name-file-test_2016-02-11_12:09:48.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [str.replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method or [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

small example:

```
mystr = "this is string example....wow!!! this is really string"
print mystr.replace(" ", "_")
print re.sub(" ","_", mystr)
```

output:

```
this_is_string_example....wow!!!_this_is_really_string
this_is_string_example....wow!!!_this_is_really_string
```